# Deduplicate levels of a factor

Tags: r

Suppose I have this object, which is the dput() form of an invalid factor (for instance, printing it will complain about the duplicate level 3):

```
x <- structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "B", "A", "C"),
               class = "factor")
```

What is the best way, using only base R, to convert it to the valid factor

```
structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor")
```

I managed to come up with

```
factor(levels(x)[x])
```

but I'm not certain that this will keep working in the future without warnings, and it's probably also quite inefficient (the real factor object that I'm trying to repair is enormous).

Comment: Interesting question. How are these invalid factors created in the first place? It might be better to fix it at the source rather than fixing it afterwards.

Comment: @JohnColeman Some dope (me) manually edited a dput() dump of a data frame, in order to reconcile two slightly different sets of names for things.  This is not practical to automate and may have to be repeated with other data sets.

Comment: I think that your `factor(levels(x)[x])` is about as good *and correct* as you're going to get. Have you profiled with the actual data to determine if/where a problem exists? Realize that you need to (a) update the levels, and (b) update the values (indices) so that they point to the correct updated levels. The fact that you are converting to `character` and back to `factor` may seem inefficient, but I can see no other way to do it with assurance of being lossless.

Comment: I just ran 1e8 random indices on `LETTERS` with 1e8 distinct levels, and it took just over 12 seconds using `factor(levels(x)[x])`; if this is reparative, that doesn't seem too bad (it took longer to create the structure than it did to refactor it). And the effective data was the same coming out as it was going in (i.e., `all(as.character(x) == as.character(factor(levels(x)[x])))`, a brute-force comparison).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method seems good, and fairly efficient. To experiment, I created a function to make such malformed factors:

```
bad.factor <- function(nums,labs){
  structure(nums, .Label = labs, class = "factor")}
```

If you use:

```
x <- bad.factor(1:1000000,gtools::chr(runif(1000000,65,90)))
```

Then run:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(factor(levels(x)[x]))
```

Typical output is:

```
 Unit: milliseconds
                 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 factor(levels(x)[x]) 27.72593 32.98346 42.97813 34.11871 35.70919 105.3564   100
```